# How to focus on first input field - redux-form

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to set the first input field in any form to be focused. So, what is the best practice to implement something like this? And how could I check the type of the field? is it text, number, checkbox or etc.?

Is it by listening to `@redux-form`  actions, and then dispatch a focus action?

Can any one suggest a solution ?

Comment: Best practice in this case is very subjective - can you share a code snippet or example you are working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that for **redux-form** (v6+) the current state of art is to provide `autoFocus` property for the `<input />` which you would like to be auto focused.

Example:

```
<Field component={renderFirstInput} type="text" />

const renderFirstInput = field => {
  return ( <input {...field.input} autoFocus /> )

}
```

[Here is the Github issue link](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1411)

You may of course provide `autoFocus` prop as a `field.input` key.

Comment: Not sure why, but my *last* element is focused rather than the first, even though *autofocus* (which I assume is the underlying property, but could be completely wrong) is meant to focus the first element that has this property set - or maybe I'm reading the docs wrong, and only *one* element can have this property set, which explains why my last element has focus

Answer (score 2):

Using this approach, you can configure your `autoFocus` every time.

```
<Field component={renderFirstInput} autoFocus={true/false} />

const renderFirstInput = ({ autoFocus }) => {
  return ( <input autoFocus={autoFocus} /> )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a great example of this exact use case in the React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use stateless functional components refs will do you no good.
My solution is to pass a first={true} prop to Field and check for it inside the component. It it exists then set autoFocus on the input field.